# Additional Routing Appended to URL After Deploying to GitHub Pages (Angular)

Tags: angular, github, github-pages

I have a website I developed with Angular (v8) and I am trying to deploy it to a custom domain using github pages.

Right now i have it successfully deployed at www.changethenarrativeproject.com however when I visit the site it gets redirected to www.changethenarrativeproject.com/ctnp.  The ctnp is the name of the project I used, but I am not sure why it is getting appended to the URL on initial load.  I was wondering if someone might be able to help out.

Here are the angular commands I am using to deploy the application so far:

```
ng build --prod -- base-href "ctnp"

ng --dir dist/ctnp
```

Can I just run these commands without "ctnp" to get my desired results?

In Google domains I have it the dns set to a Type A, TTL 1h and 185.199.108.153, as well as a CNAME of my github pages directory.

The error this is causing is that when I navigate to www.changethenarrativeproject.com, it will redirec to /ctnp and then if I refresh it the page will error out.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve by running

```
ng build --prod --base-href ""
```

instead of

```
ng build --prod --base-href "ctnp"
```

Thanks